# how to convert Mat.at<cv::Vec3b>() from C++ opencv to Mat for C# opencvsharp?

Tags: c#, opencv

I want to convert C++ OpenCV Code to C# OpenCVSharp.

But i don't know how to replace this code

```
cv::Mat mat;
mat.at<cv::vec3b>(int,int)[c] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha*(image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c]) + beta);
```

I already know that uchar is replaced by byte. but i have tried many things, but i only see errors in visual studio. so i have no idea how to handle it.

This is C++ code

```
cv::Mat TextureFiltering::BrightContrast(const cv::Mat &image, double alpha, int beta)
{
    CV_Assert(image.depth() == CV_8U);

    cv::Mat result;
    result.create(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());

    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < image.channels(); c++)
            {
                result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha*(image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c]) + beta);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is C# code(incomplete)

```
public Mat BrightContrast(Mat m, double alpha, int beta)
{
    Mat result = m.Clone();
    result.Create(m.Rows, m.Cols, m.Type());

    for (int i = 0; i < m.Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.Cols; j++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < m.Channels(); c++)
            {
                // I don't know what code to put here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate your answers. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Opencv convert to opencvsharp

`result.at<cv::Vec3b> (i, j)[c]`  to  `result.At<Vec3b>(i, j)[c]`

if you want to set value like opencv in opencvsharp, for example:

`result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c] = 10;`

you can refer to this link 
https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/Vec3b/-/php-vec3b-class-examples.html